# Riggan arriving in cab at the theater

Tags: plot-explanation, birdman

In the movie Birdman (2014), could you also explain the scene when we see Riggan jumping off a roof (when a man comes to stop him and asks if he knows where he wanted to go), flying above the city  and then arriving at the theater in a cab?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of either [that](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28785/49) or [that](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27608/49).

Comment: Just this part then..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Riggan didn't actually jump off the roof or fly, those were just manifestations in his mind.  If you recall, it was somewhat implied that he flew right to the theater and walked in, and then you saw the taxi and realized he must have taken the taxi to the theater since he can't really fly.

Comment: ..and he forgets to pay the fare too. This explains that in his mind he thought he flew to the theater and so he didn't feel the need to pay the fare. Thanks. Rep too low to vote up.